# variable amplitude sine wave matlab

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

Attempting to generate a sine function with several different amplitude epochs withinf the same trace.

For example, a 2Hz sine wave at amplitude 1 for 10 seconds, amplitude 10 for ten sceonds, then back to amplitude 1 for another ten seconds.

I tried editing the example here: http://www.mathworks.se/help/slcontrol/ug/frest.sinestream.html
but got errors with the code:

```
input = frest.Sinestream('Frequency',[2 2 2],...
         'Amplitude',[1 10 1],...
         'FreqUnits','Hz',...
         'SamplesPerPeriod',[40 40 40],...
         'RampPeriods',[0 0 0],...
         'SettlingPeriods',[1 1 1]);
      plot(input)
```

Errors received from this are:

```
Error using frest.Sinestream/set.Frequency (line 127)
The "Frequency" parameter of a sinestream signal should be a double vector consisting of unique values.

Error in frest.Sinestream/initializeParams (line 508)
                obj.(varargin{2*ct-1}) = varargin{2*ct};

Error in frest.Sinestream (line 80)
            obj = initializeParams(obj,inputparams{:});

Error in sine (line 1)
input = frest.Sinestream('Frequency',[2 2 2],...
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Have you tried leaving `Frequency` as a scalar (value 2), and the other parameters as arrays? Not sure you need `SettlingPeriods` but you probably want to specify `NumPeriods`.

Comment: Leaving frequency as a scalar results in a new set of errors, even when every other parameter is kept the same as the example in the link, which works fine.

Comment: It looks like you can't have duplicate values in the `Frequency` vector, but I don't see this limitation being documented anywhere. What error do you get with a scalar frequency?

Comment: Error using frest.Sinestream/checkSizeAgainstFrequency (line 265)
The value of the "Amplitude" parameter of a sinestream signal must be of compatible size with the value of parameter "Frequency".

Error in frest.Sinestream/checkSizeConsistency (line 271)
            if ~isempty(obj.Amplitude_),checkSizeAgainstFrequency(obj,obj.Amplitude_,'Amplitude'); end;

Error in frest.Sinestream/initializeParams (line 535)
            checkSizeConsistency(obj);

Error in frest.Sinestream (line 80)
                obj = initializeParams(obj,inputparams{:});

Comment: Error in Untitled8 (line 1)
input = frest.Sinestream('Frequency',(2),...

Comment: OK, then I suggest using Dennis' suggestion

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be as simple as this:

```
x=0:0.005:30;
y = sin(x*2000);

idx = 10<x & x < 20;
y(idx) = 10*y(idx);

plot(x,y)
```

Of course this may give some rough transitions at the changing points if the value is not zero there. This is illustrated by this example:

```
x=0:0.005:30;
y = sin(x);

idx = 10<x & x < 20;
y(idx) = 10*y(idx);

plot(x,y)
```

Comment: The idea is a good one, but the frequency is slightly wrong: you want 

`f = 2;
t=0:1e-3:30;
x = sin(2*pi*f*t);
idx = 10<t & t<20;
x(idx)=10*x(idx);
plot(t,x)`

and yes, the transition isn't a smooth one (clearly visible if you zoom in on the plot)